# laravel error while installing using composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

> ayat@ayat-Win MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/laravel $ composer
> create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel cms Creating a
> "laravel/laravel" project at "./cms" Installing laravel/laravel
> (v7.12.0)
>
> - Installing laravel/laravel (v7.12.0): Loading from cache Created project in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\cms  @php -r "file_exists('.env')
>   || copy('.env.example', '.env');" Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Package operations: 99 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
> - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.5.2): Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.18.0): Loading from cache   **- Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5): Downloading (failed)**
>   **Downloading (failed)**
>   **Downloading (failed)    Failed to download phpoption/phpoption from dist:** The
>   "https://api.github.com/repos/schmittjoh/php-option/zipball/994ecccd8f3283ecf5ac33254543eb0ac946d525"
>   file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.
>
>   Now trying to download from source

Comment: please check your internet connection and  use vpn or proxy to create laravel project

Comment: What happens if you try to open the link in a browser? https://api.github.com/repos/schmittjoh/php-option/zipball/994ecccd8f3283ecf5ac33254543eb0ac946d525

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper why my system is not able to download?